# Не получается добавить данные в БД, используя pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

Есть следующий код:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='host_name',user='user_name',password='db_pasword',db='db_name',charset='utf8')
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO `textsfornn` (`id`, `tender_id`, `text`, `category_id`) VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, ("test", "test",  "test"))
print(cursor.fetchone())
```

Но почему-то в после его выполнения в Б.Д ничего не добавляться.

Структура Б.Д:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых добавьте

```
connection.commit()
```

после

```
cursor.execute()
```

Во вторых `cursor.fetchone()` не имеет особого смысла, т.к. это курсор для вставки (`INSERT`) данных, а не для чтения (`SELECT`).